# table settings for multiple columns

Tags: tables

I think this is a very basic question, but I could not find an answer, maybe because I don't know the right words to search for. I am using the siunitx package to align numbers in a table. Since my table has several columns, I don't want to copy and paste the settings for each column like:

`\begin{tabular}{lS[table-number-alignment=left]S[table-number-alignment=left]S[table-number-alignment=left]S[table-number-alignment=left]S[table-number-alignment=left]}`

I am searching for a notation like this, but it does not work:

`\begin{tabular}{l 5*S[table-number-alignment=left]}`

Maybe someone does know how to write this better or point me to the correct documentation, where this is explained. Thanks!

Comment: Use `*{num}{cols}`, see https://latexref.xyz/tabular.html#tabular. In your example, it should be `*{5}{S[...]}`.

Comment: If your tabular is in a group (like a table environment), you might simply add at the beginning of the group `\sisetup{table-number-alignment=left}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhi Z: It works! Thanks! If you post this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported syntax is `*{num}{cols}`, see latexref.xyz/tabular.html#tabular. Hence in your example, it should be

```
\begin{tabular}{ l *{5}{S[...]} }
```

Also as @Bernard mentioned in [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555606/table-settings-for-multiple-columns?noredirect=1#comment1402511_555606), if your tabular is in a group (like a `table` environment), you might simply use

```
\begin{table}
  \sisetup{table-number-alignment=left}
  \begin{tabular}{l *{5}{S}} % here braces around "5" and "S" are both optional
    content
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```